# Add Marker / update if exists

Tags: leaflet

The expresion below adds a new marker on each click.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {
    var new_event_marker = L.marker(e.latlng, { draggable: true} );     
    new_event_marker.addTo(map);        
});
```

How can I rewrite the above so it creates only one marker? If the marker exists update its latlng.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

First you should define your marker outside click function. And then you can test if marker exist or not. Folowing code should work:

```
var new_event_marker;  // replace marker

map.on('click', function(e) {

 if(typeof(new_event_marker)==='undefined')
 {
  new_event_marker = new L.marker(e.latlng,{ draggable: true});
  new_event_marker.addTo(map);        
 }
 else 
 {
  new_event_marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);         
 }
});
```